# Не компилируется код в InteliJIDIA

Tags: selenium

```
package x.selenium.tests;

import x.selenium.pages.Register;

import org.junit.*;

import static org.fest.assertions.Assertions.assertThat;
import static org.junit.Assert.*;

import org.openqa.selenium.*;

public class RegistrationTest1 extends Register{

    private Register register;
    private WebDriver driver11;
    private boolean acceptNextAlert = true;
    private StringBuffer verificationErrors = new StringBuffer();

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        register.Initial();
    }

    @Test
    public void correctRegisterTest() {
        register.NewUserRegistration();
        register.Logout();
        register.Download();
        register.Logout();
    }

    @After
    public void tearDown() throws Exception {
       driver11.quit();
        String verificationErrorString = verificationErrors.toString();
        if (!"".equals(verificationErrorString)) {
            fail(verificationErrorString);
        }
    }
}
```

Ругается `java.lang.NullPointerException x.selenium.tests.RegistrationTest1.setUp
java.lang.NullPointerException x.selenium.tests.RegistrationTest1.tearDown`
Хотя метода setUp у меня вообще не было.

Answer (score 3):

У вас не инициализирован поля `register` и `driver11`. Как метода `setUp` не было? Вот же:

```
public void setUp() throws Exception {
    register.Initial();
}
```